# Split numbers from a string (can also be decimal number)

Tags: javascript, regex

Lately iv'e been trying to find some ways to manipulate a string (for some project of mine) and i'm having a hard finding something that will mach my case.
usually the string will include 3 numbers (can also be decimal - that's what make it more complicated) and separated by 1 / 2 signs ("-", "x", "*" and so on...)
i did some research online and found this solution (which i thought it was good) 
`.match(/\d+/g)`
when i tried it on some case the result was good

`var word = "9-6x3"
word = word.match(/\d+/g)`

it gave me array with 3 indexes, each index held a number `['9', '6', '3']` (which is good), but if the string had a dot (decimal number) this regex would have ignored it.
i need some regex which can ignore the dots in a string but can achieve the same result.
case =
`var word = "9.5-9.3x7"` output = `['9.5', '9.3', '7']`

Comment: `['9,5', ...]` looks wrong. because `[...9.3, 7]` part looks like a real pattern

Comment: @zer00ne i made an edit. anyway the type of the indexes in the array doesnt really matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression to allow for an optional decimal place:

```
word.match(/\d+([\.]\d+)?/g)
```

This says:

- \d+  - any number of digits
- ([\.]\d+)? - optionally one decimal point followed by digits

Comment: it fits perfect for what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple regex that suits your requirement,

`/\d+\.?\d*/g`

Comment: I just checked it and it worked, Thank you.

Comment: this will also match if there are multiple decimal points (like word="9...5-7" gives `[ '9...5', '7' ]`

Comment: that still doesn't work.  if word="9.5-7" you get `[ '9.5' ]` and miss the 7

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sorry, I edited it wrongly. Now it's corrected

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan
I just checked AlwaysLearning answer and it seems like it fits better to what i need, but thank you anyway.